# JQuery Mobile - Panel - data-display="push" doesn't work

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

This is my page :

```
<body>
 <div role="main">
    <div data-role="panel" id="userMenu" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="g">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
            <li id="menuTxt" data-role="list-divider">Menu</li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/Home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/CheckFridge">Mes ingr&eacute;dients</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/AddRecipe">Ajouter une recette</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="#">D&eacute;connexion</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/MyRecipes">Mes recettes</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/">Partager</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="menuBtn" href="#userMenu"></a>
        <img id="icook_logo" src="~/Content/images/icook_logo.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="ui-content">
        <a data-role="button" href="@Url.Action("Index", "CheckFridge")" data-theme="c" data-ajax="false" id="checkFridgeBtn">Check mon frigo</a>
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="c" id="classicSearch">Recherche classique</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

The problem when I click on the button sitting on the top-left of the page, the rest of the page doesn't move to the right in spite of that the attribute "data-position" is equals to "left"

[image]

[image]

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Your html structure is incorrect. Replace `role=main` with `data-role=page`.

Comment: I use JQuery Mobile 1.4 and I replaced role=main with data-role=page but so, all the content of the page is in below

Comment: what do you mean by "in the below"?

Comment: All the content of my page is on bottom of my page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/w256s/ replace `role="main"` with `data-role="page"` and `data-role="ui-content"` with `role="main class="ui-content"`. This is a simple jQM page structure.